# Setting up a many to many relationship. Cube

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssas, cube

Can I create a many to many relationship in SSAS in this case:

1. Recursive table – key, parent_id
2. Table containing key from the recursive table and key from measures table
3. Measures table

Steps I take:

1. Create a cube without the recursive table dimension
2. Add new measure of counting rows of the bridge table
3. Add new dimension of the recursive table

When I try to set up Dimension Usage of the Recursive Table to Many to Many with Measures table it tells me that no intermediate measures group or dimension table exists where I have created it in point 2

Links in SSAS:

RecursiveTable --> BridgeTable <-- MeasuresTable

```
CustomerTable     Bridge        MeasureTable
Id(PK)            CustId(PK)        Id (PK)
CustomerId         Id           CountMeasure
ParentId
DepName
```

Comment: Your question is too generic.  Give us some proper nouns so we can better understand your model.

Comment: When you have a many to many relationship between your dimension table and your fact, you usually have a grain problem or a relationship problem.  Start by reviewing those.

Comment: I have added the design of the data, hope this will do. Thanks

Comment: What is your measure?  Sales?  What does the bridge represent?  Be more descriptive so we better understand your problem.  Explain it in business terms. You should not have a many to many relationship between a Fact and Dimension.  If you do you have a design problem.  For example, a sale that has multiple customer contacts is likely a sale for an account, and the account has multiple contacts.  You're missing a layer to the relationship.